# Checksum error after crash install Android

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode

I wanted to **upgrade my Android phone *(Acer Liquid Ferrari)* from 2.2 to 2.3** but it crashed => I can't turn on my phone,

When I do a clean boot (power + vol up + vol down) there are no problem but my phone doesn't reboot

When I want to go into Recovery (power + vol up + cam) there are an error on the checksum

```
Partition: checksum
 splash: chsum =00000000 OK
 boot:chcksum=8fa17e51 != 0021fde4 **fail**
 recovery:chsum =00000000 OK
 system:chsum =00000000 OK
=====
<<FAIL>>
```

So when I want to do `adb devices` I have `error device not found`. The driver is correctly installed on my computer

How can I launch the recovery mode ?

Thanks

Comment: You probably should give you device's make and model for more specific answers.

Comment: Acer Liquid Ferrari

Comment: And your computer is running what OS/version? Devices show up using different device IDs when booted into different "modes" (normal boot/recovery/...), so that might need additional configuration/drivers.

Comment: I use Windows OS (but I have also Ubuntu). What kind of driver is necessary in more ?

Comment: Or are there a Windows application which can help me to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by connecting my phone to usb and pressing Vol Up + Cam + Power for await my PC recognize the device. 
After that, I use Acer Tools to flash my device with the bin of Android